# Node wrapper: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, api, wrapper, stack-overflow

I'm building a Node wrapper for an [API](https://www.lob.com/docs) and am receiving a stack overflow error when attaching a pdf file in a `POST` request to the server.

The core logic is in `src/lob.coffee`:

```
fs = require "fs"

USER_AGENT = "Lob: Node Wrapper"

API_HOST = "https://api.lob.com"
API_PATH = "/v1"

module.exports = lob = (api_key) ->

  request = (method, path, data, cb) ->

    request_object = {
      method : method,
      uri : "#{API_HOST}#{API_PATH}#{path}",
      headers : {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Connection" : "close",
        "User-Agent" : USER_AGENT
      },
      auth : {
        user : api_key,
        pass : ""
      }
    }

    if typeof data is "function"
      cb = data

    r = request request_object, (err, res, body) ->
      body = JSON.parse(body)
      if body.errors? and err is null
        err = body.errors
        delete body.errors
      cb err, body
      this

    if method is "POST_FORM"
      form = r.form()
      Object.keys(data).forEach (_k) ->
        form.append _k, data[_k]
      this

  objects:
    createObject: (data, cb) ->
      path = "/objects"
      data.file = fs.createReadStream data.file.substr 1
      request "POST_FORM", path , data, cb
```

And I wrote this basic file in `test/manual.coffee` for testing the functionality:

```
api_key = "test_0dc8d51e0acffcb1880e0f19c79b2f5b0cc"
lob     = require('../src/lob')(api_key)

object2 =
  name: "TEST"
  file: "@/Users/Admin/Downloads/test.pdf"
  setting_id: 100

lob.objects.createObject object2, (err, res) ->
  console.log err, res
```

But when I run the test file, I receive the following error: `ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`and I'm not sure what the cause of this would be.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion

```
objects:
    createObject: (data, cb//here) ->
      path = "/objects"
      data.file = fs.createReadStream data.file.substr 1
      request "POST_FORM", path , data, cb //here
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure why this would cause recursion?